# Contact Form 7 - Delay auto responds

Tags: functions, email

I'm looking for a way to delay the auto response (mail_2) from Contact Form 7 for 2 days. But I have no clue how to tackle it. I hope you have an idea.

I'm using the following code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'send_custom_respond' );

function send_custom_respond($WPCF7_ContactForm) {

  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
  $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
  $contact_name = $posted_data['your-name'];
  $contact_email = $posted_data['your-email'];

  $mail_2 = $WPCF7_ContactForm->prop('mail_2') ;
  $mail_2['subject'] = "Enjoying the trial?";
  $mail_2['body'] = "Hi ". $contact_name . ",\n how's the trial? Let us know if you need some assistance.";

  $WPCF7_ContactForm->set_properties(array("mail_2" => $mail_2));

  return $WPCF7_ContactForm;
}
```

Comment: Given that the submissions are not stored in the database, you won't be able to delay sending unless you save the submission somewhere. Have a look at [Download
Contact Form 7 Database Addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/) or [Contact Form 7 Database](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-database/) as you may be able to create a cron script and plugin to scan this table and send an email for any submissions after 2 days.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue maybe?